# How to split multiple values from a dataframe column into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with multiple values. I want to split the unique values into multiple columns with headers and then apply Label Encoder or One Hot Encoder(I don't know yet) because I have a Multi-label text classification problem to solve.

I try

```
df['labels1'] = df['labels1'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

but it splits only the first item. Also before try to split the column I try to change the type but I didn't make it.

```
id
0           Politics, Journals, International
1                  Social, Blogs, Celebrities
2                         Media, Blogs, Video
3                         Food&Drink, Cooking
4                         Media, Blogs, Video
5                                     Culture
6                            Social, TV Shows
7                       News, Crime, National
8                  Social, Blogs, Celebrities
9                  Social, Blogs, Celebrities
10                 Social, Blogs, Celebrities
11                              Family, Blogs
12                        Media, Blogs, Video
13                           Social, TV Shows
14                    Entertainment, TV Shows
15                           Social, TV Shows
16                 Social, Blogs, Celebrities
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for the right side of the equation of df['labels1'].str.split(',', expand=True) would spit out two items.  So perhaps you can do something like:

```
df['newcolumn1'], df['newcolumn2'] = df['labels1'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to set a column of a dataframe with a three-columns-dataframe - which unfortunately silently is done by passing only the first column...
Perhaps you try to concatenate the new three expanded columns to the first dataframe

```
df = pd.concat([df, df['labels1'].str.split(', ', expand=True)], 1)
```

or perhaps just go on with this step in a new one

```
df_exp = df['labels1'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

---

Edit:

IIUC, your binary table *can* be created like this (but I don't know if this is the recommended way to do):

```
col_head = set(df.labels1.str.split(', ', expand=True).values.flatten())

bin_tbl = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_head)

for c in bin_tbl:
    bin_tbl[c] = df.labels1.str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: c in x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response....Your second solution split the column. I have another question. I would like for each unique value in **label1** column to put them as a header and then to do a MultiLabelBinarizer. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Just to be correct: both commands contain the same split part, so they create the same result. The difference is where it is stored. Furthermore, if you "_have another question_", you should normally go on and create and post exactly that: another question.